# python3 read xml subcollection

Tags: xml, python-3.x

with that approach I successfully read the first collection of items.

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom

# Open XML document using minidom parser
DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse("Test.xml")
collection = DOMTree.documentElement

#Get all items
items = collection.getElementsByTagName("item")

for item in items:
```

items have a sub collection of sub items. How can I read the subcollection of collection items in python3 ?

Comment: If you are not forced to use the DOM imlementation, I suggest to use the xml.etree.ElementTree standard module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Comment: looks like that module is also just good for the first sub element. But as it supports XPath it might be a solution. Thanks